# Child process not killed - Node js ( inside Electron js app, windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, child-process

I am trying to stop this command after 4 seconds, but it doesn't stop the child-process
(Running in an electron-js app, windows )

```
child = child_process.spawn("ping google.com -t", {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  shell: true
});

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  //Here is the output
  data=data.toString();
  
  console.log(data)
});


setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Killing Your child', child.pid);
  child.kill()
}, 4 * 1000);
```

the timeout runs after 4 seconds, it logs the message but never stops the process

I tried using tags inside the kill() like "SIGINT" or "SIGKILL"

I tried running without the timeout too...

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [official documentation for child process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) I have slightly modified your provided example to a bare minimum of what still seems to work for me. Please note that the `ping -t` flag requires an argument which you didn't provide.

The following worked for me (the program exits after 4 pings) on Node LTS (16.15.1) and the latest version (18.4.0):

```js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn("ping", ['www.google.com'], {});
child.stdout.on('data', (data) => { console.log(data.toString()); });

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Killing Your child', child.pid);
  child.kill();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`shell: true` doesn't work with `.kill()`
as you can see in the answer from this post:

[Try to kill a spawn process with shell true and detached true nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007825/try-to-kill-a-spawn-process-with-shell-true-and-detached-true-nodejs)

I needed to replace:

```
child.kill()
```

with

```
  child_process.spawn("taskkill", ["/pid", child.pid, '/f', '/t']);
```